# How to type available request methods, params, and result?

Tags: typescript

The objective is to have types that satisfy,

1. A `request(method: TMethod, params: TParams): TReturn` function where both `TParams` and `TReturn` are inferred when the user provides a method.
2. The method values should be accessible as values to consumers (exports). E.g, via an Enum, although doesn't have to be an enum.
3. The `method` arg can be provided as either a string or (assuming we're using an enum for #2) something like `Methods.myMethod`.

```
request("myMethod") // OK
request(Methods.myMethod) // OK
request("invalidMethod") // TS Error
```

4. Inside the `request` method, type narrowing should work by checking the value of `method`

```
function request(method, params) {
    if (method === "myMethod") {
        // `params` type is known here
    }
}
```

The closest I've got to what I want (which only covers #1) looks like,

```
interface Requests {
  method1: {
    params: {
      p11: string;
      p12: string;
    };
    response: {
      r11: string;
      r12: string;
    };
  };
  method2: {
    params: {
      p21: boolean;
    };
    response: {
      r21: number;
    };
  };
}

type Res<Method> = Method extends keyof Requests
  ? Requests[Method]["response"]
  : never;
type Params<Method> = Method extends keyof Requests
  ? Requests[Method]["params"]
  : never;

function request<Method extends keyof Requests>(
  method: Method,
  params: Params<Method>
): Res<Method> {
  // fn body
}
```

Is it possible to achieve #2, #3, & #4 with Typescript? [TS Playground minimum reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by "are not available as exports"?  Do you not have `keyof Requests`?  Please [edit] the code in your question to be a [mre] that demonstrates your problem and not unrelated problems. Right now if I look at your code [in an IDE](https://tsplay.dev/wjoe6N) I see problems you're not asking about and nothing that clearly demonstrates the issue you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've update the code, hopefully it makes it clearer. The method string values themselves, e.g., `"method1"`, can't be referenced as a values. Not only am I interested in the types, but also allowing users to import and reference a specific method value, something like `methods.method1; // "method1"`

Comment: Why would you need to import string values? In what sense is `methods.method1` preferable to `"method1"`?  Could you please make a [mre] that demonstrates the problem you’re experiencing? It would presumably involve trying to make a call to `request()` which fails in some way or has some obvious issue. Right now there’s only a verbal description of the issue, and it’s not clear (to me anyway) what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, and sorry for the ambiguous verbal description. The issue is that I don't know how to construct types that allow having *both* a typed `request` function (which I've successfully achieved above) *and* access to the methods as string values. In the context I'm working in currently, the values may be used in several code bases, and it is desirable to have access to the values rather than having hard coded strings in the code base.

Comment: But… can’t you provide a [mre] that demonstrates this? And again, how is `"xyz"` any more “hard coded” than `foo.xyz`? Is it the quotation marks?

Comment: @jcalz I've update the question, is what I'm trying to achieve clear now?

Comment: Without a [mre] I can paste into my IDE and immediately get started, I can't tell. It's also been several weeks since I asked for clarification, so while this question might be fresh enough in your mind, it's completely paged out of my working memory. Right now everything looks like pure pseudocode (does `request` take one arg or two? Is it `"myMethod"` or `"method1"`/`"method2"`) so it means to even get working on this I need to essentially delete everything and start from scratch. The point of a [mre] is to be a common base people can work from. If you provide one I'll look again. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the lightning-fast response! I've added a link to the TS Playground with an MRE. Does it help with finding a solution? Thanks

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpo4gN) work for your objectives 1 & 4? I'd suggest removing references to 2 & 3 here since your example already essentially works for it, it's not clear what more you want (make an enum if you want one, I guess), and it's really unrelated to the other objectives except that you have them both happening in your code (SO questions are best when they have narrow scope so that future readers are more likely to have the same issue and so that answers can be focused and not have separate sections about what are essentially separate questions).